# Starting a member function with arguments in a separate thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, stdthread

I have a member function `MyClass::doStuff(QString & str)`

I am trying to call that function from a thread like this:

```
std::thread thr(&MyClass::doStuff, this);
```

However, that results in an error:

`/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/functional:1697: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<std::_Mem_fn<void (MyClass::*)(QString&)>(MyClass*)>’
       typedef typename result_of<_Callable(_Args...)>::type result_type;`

So I've attempted to give it the argument:

```
QString a("test");
std::thread thr(&MyClass::doStuff(a), this);
```

However, that results in this error: `lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand`

How would I go about running that member function with an argument, from a separate thread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add the arguments to the thread's constructor:

```
QString a("test");
std::thread thr(&MyClass::doStuff, this, a);
```

As your function accepts a *reference* you should use `std::ref()` like this:

```
MyClass::doStuff(QString& str) { /* ... */ }

// ...

QString a("test");
std::thread thr(&MyClass::doStuff, this, std::ref(a)); // wrap references
```

Comment: Question: since `doStuff` ask for a reference but it is running in another thread, there is nothing stopping you from deleting `a` and you will end up with a UB?

Comment: @Ceros Of course, if you delete a variable something else is using there will be trouble :)

Comment: what is the purpose of `std::ref` in this case?

Comment: So apparently it's for template type deduction

Comment: @Ceros It puts the variable in a `std::reference_wrapper` http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref It is needed when passing parameters that are accepted as references.